# procedurally combine a main character with weapons during animations

Tags: procedural-generation, procedural

I need to find a way to programmatically place weapons for main character in right position of his body.

For example if I am using UMA to procedurally create humans and then use some pre-existing models of guns (10-20) of them. Now I need to find a way to place them correctly in the hand positions of the human model. I will use mixamo or IK to apply animations on the human character.

But is there any way to programmatically place the objects in the right positions? Probably by marking some joints?

I am looking at some efficient **approach** to begin with on this.

Answer (score 3):

The general approach here is to define some notion of "sockets" in the character skeleton. These need to encode position (where the attached thing should be) and rotation (which direction should the attached thing face), and as such can be represented as transforms relative to a parent, and as such are basically just specifically-named or designated bones in a skeletal rig. You can treat them separately if you like, however.

Then it's just a matter of creating some kind of attachment structure that pairs an object to another object at a specific socket or bone, and making sure the animation system knows to follow these attachments and apply the appropriated transform to the attached object during update of the skeleton.